# Saving list as an image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save a 2D list as an image in python (greyscale image) so 0 values in the array would be black and 255 would be white. For example:

```
255 255 255
255  0  255
255  0  255
255  0  255
255 255 255
```

Would save an l like shape. 
I have tried the following code utilising the PIL library as suggested by other questions on stack overflow:

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size
imgData = list(img.getdata()) 
imgData = [imgData[offset:offset + WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH * HEIGHT, WIDTH)]
#to print the image 
for row in data:
    print(' '.join('{:3}'.format(value) for value in row))
imgData = np.array(imgData)
**IMG VALUES AUGMENTED HERE**
newimg = Image.new('L', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), 'white')
newimg.putdata(imgData)
newimg.save('C:/File/Name.png')
```

However the image this creates does not reflect the list at all. If I was to have the 0s and 255s in different positions the same image is created. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: What's the exact structure of imgData? is it `[[255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 255], ...`, or [255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, ...]`?

Comment: So for the code I am using it is a much bigger list around 40 x 60 and I am using the code:

`WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size`
`imgData = list(img.getdata())`
`imgData = [imgData[offset:offset + WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH * HEIGHT, WIDTH)]`
Does that help?

Comment: Can you edit that code into the question? And put the rest of the for loop?

Comment: Sorry had issues formatting the reply there. You're right, would be better to add this to the main question

Comment: Yeah no problem, also might run into maximum comment length issues.

Comment: Thats all the relevant code added now. Hope that helps!

Comment: I suspect you need to explicitly set the data type when creating the Numpy array, like this `imgData = np.array(imgData, dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this didnt help either

Answer (score 1):

As your example is lacking any input data, I have just typed it in as you describe, made the image and then enlarged it. I also artificially added a red border so you can see the extent of it on StackOverflow's white background:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pixels = [[255,255,255],
          [255,0,255],
          [255,0,255],
          [255,0,255],
          [255,255,255]]

# Make list of pixels into Image
im = Image.fromarray(np.array(pixels,dtype=np.uint8))
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
newimg.putdata(imgData)
```

you need the line:

```
newimg.putdata([j[0] for i in imgData for j in i])
```

The grayscale data is specified in a 1d list, not a 2d list.

This creates the list:

```
>>> [j[0] for i in imgData for j in i]
[255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

Which is:

```
[255, 255, 255,
 255,  0 , 255, 
 255,  0 , 255, 
 255,  0 , 255, 
 255, 255, 255]
```

EDIT
The above solution works if you edit `imgData` with `imgData[0][0] = [0, 0, 0, 255]`. If you're editing `imgData` with `imgData[0][0] = 0`, then you'll need the line to be:

```
[j[0] if hasattr(j, '__iter__') else j for i in imgData for j in i]
```

or, you can make it nicer with:

```
imgData = np.array([[j[0] for j in i] for i in imgData])
imgData[0][0] = 0
newimg.putdata(imgData.flatten())
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion although I am getting the error "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable." for that new line. Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: I'm still encountering an error with 'imgData = np.array([[j[0] for j in i] for i in imgData])' line. Now the error is ''int object' is not subscriptable'
Just to make sure I'm piecing the code together properly should it be in this order:
https://gyazo.com/19eb248e7f68fb85cb36a5f6ebc4cbc3

Comment: @JackTimber Interesting, that code works on my system. It must be that our `img.getdata` outputs are different. How are you loading the image?